# Llamar Modal desde myModal.php a mi index.php

Tags: php, modal

Tengo 1 Modal en el archivo llamado myModal.php. Quiero llamar este archivo desde el index.php sin que me redireccione a myModal.php, es decir, que se ejecute el modal (myModal.php) permaneciendo en el indice de la pagina.

He intentado con el codigo que le comparto a continuación, pero me redirecciona a la pagina myModal y no es lo quiero, ya que deseo permanecer en la pagina desde la que realizo el llamado.

Gracias por su atención.

```
//Archivo index.php

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center js-fullheight slider-text">
        <div class="slider-text-inner">
            <p><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="myModal.php#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">¡Solicita tu Reserva!</a></p>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//Archivo myModal.php

```
<?php
require "class/Db.class.php";
require "class/Conf.class.php";
$bd = Db::getInstance(); 
?>


<div class="container">
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">My Modal</h4>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- fin modal-content -->
        </div> <!-- fin  modal-dialog -->
    </div> <!-- fin  modal-fade -->
```

Comment: Probaste incluyendo el archivo myModal.php en index.php. <?php include 'myModal.php'; ?> dentro del include pone la direccion de donde esta alojado el modal

Comment: deberías mandarlo llamar en el momento que gustes ! <?php include 'Mymodal.php';?>

Comment: Correcto!!!! Gracias....

Comment: para no crear otro topic, resulta que cuando agrego 2 modales include por ejemplo en el index, solo me funciona uno, alguna solución?